# Django How to bulk update on all child objects?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am building help desk system on django. Where anyone can open ticket for customer support.
Assume I have an parent object #001 and every child object of this parent have same ticket id. See the screenshot for better understand:
[image]

child1 and child2 have same ticket id like their parent object. How to apply bulk update on all objects if they have same ticket id?. Assume if I change ticket status of child2 then I want it will also apply bulk update of child1 and parent object. any idea how to do that on django?
here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
       choice = (("pending","pending"),("solved","solved"),("closed","closed"))
       ticket_status = models.CharField(choices=choice,max_length=100,default="pending")
       parent =models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                  null=True, blank=True, related_name='contact_parent')
       sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)


       def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
          if not self.parent and not self.support_ticket:
              self.support_ticket= str(rand_support_ticket())
          if not self.support_ticket:
               self.support_ticket = self.parent.support_ticket
          
       
          
          super(Contact,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SupportAgentFrom(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Contact
         fields = ['support_message','ticket_status']
```

**views.py**

```
def AddReplySupport(request,slug):

    # fetch the object related to passed id
    obj = get_object_or_404(Contact, slug = slug)

    # pass the object as instance in form
    form = SupportAgentFrom(request.POST or None, instance = obj)   
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.support_agent = request.user
        form.save()
```

now I can update only single object once at a time. I want to apply bulk update on multiple objects at a time if they have same ticket id.

**#Update1**
Finally my problem is solved after following Dan Yishai solution. Here I want to try little bit explain his code so people can understand and solve this type of similar problems which I was facing.

```
Contact.objects.filter(
                      Q(support_ticket=form.instance.support_ticket) 
                  ).update( ticket_status="closed")
```

Above line of code searching and updating only those objects whose have exactly same ticket id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the item and all of it's children in a single query, just replace your code inside the if with something like:

```py
count = Contact.objects.filter(
    Q(pk=form.instance.pk) | Q(parent_id=form.instance.pk)
).update(support_agent=request.user)
```

You can use `count` to verify at least 1 object has been updated, and display to the user how many objects were modified.

Comment: Dan Yishai Thanks. It's worked after little modification of your code. You give very simple and easy solution. Thanks again.

Comment: What did you improve? So we could change the answer for any future viewers...

Comment: see my updated question. I just changed the fields name

Answer (score 1):

Below I'm assuming `sno` is the Ticket Id
To grab the queryset:

```
queryset = Contact.objects.filter(sno=form.instance.sno)
```

Now you can use `.update()` or `.bulk_update()`.

Update every object to have the same support agent:

```
queryset.update(support_agent=request.user)
```

Update every object to have a different support agent:

```
for contact in queryset:
    contact.support_agent = value

queryset.bulk_update['support_agent']
```

Comment: what I will insert for `value`.  what will be actual value for this linke `contact.support_agent = value`

Comment: In your case in this specific example you do not need to use bulk_update. But if you wanted to change a field for every object and wanted to assign different values to that field for each object, then bulk_update becomes useful